# advanced rollover to display extra options

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have a web app that has a list of user comments.  I want extra options for these comments (vote, reply, etc..) to appear only when the comment itself is mouseover-ed

The best example of what I am looking for would be a youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2VzLn6DMCE&ob=av3e

When you go to the comments the options (reply, vote up/down) are only displayed when that specific comment is rolled-over.  How is this achieved? Is it simply a matter of using jquery (or similar javascript library) and displaying hidden divs?

Edit:

Ok so the element I am rolling over is complicated that I need to do it with javascript. I'm using rails, so prototype it is! Each of the individual list items has a unique id, but I have no idea how to pass this id variable into the prototype! This way it can display/hide the elements from a specific list item. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: "This video contains content from EMI. It is not available in your country." *shakes fist at the music industry*

Comment: that's too bad, it's a great video for a mediocre radiohead song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is the best way, in my opinion.  Here's a vertical way:

HTML:

```
<div class='roller'>
  <div>Options</div>
  <div>Comments</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.roller { overflow:hidden; height:30px;line-height:30px }
.roller:hover { height:60px }
```

And here's a horizontal way, with the same HTML:

CSS:

```
.roller { overflow:hidden;width:100px }
.roller div { width:100px;float:left }
.roller:hover { width:200px }
```

A little creative margin/padding work and you can get different results.

Also, you can use `first-child` and/or next sibling selectors, or others.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS might be an option, but I think I'd handle the show/hide with Jquery so that I could have total access over each element.  This way, I could potentially conditionally show/hide elements based on login, session, etc.

[Jquery How-To](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide)

You'd still want to build the divs out to contain your icons, and position with CSS.  The background change could also be handled with Jquery, via the [.css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: What if the user has JS turned off?

Comment: frankly i'm not too worried if the users have js turned off..my users are relatively young and web savvy.  If they have js turned off then screw em, I don't want them. But I like both methods.

Comment: @Steve, it's honestly less of an issue than you think.  Plus, the show/hide capability of Jquery is progressive enhancement, so those with the "questionable browsers" will simply not get the enhancements.